# Integrating Birt report viewer in Springboot Thymleaf application

Tags: spring, report, birt

Is it possible to embed Birt report viewer inside my SPringboot+Thymleaf application?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. I've done it myself. Here are a couple of websites to get you started.

[https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-mvc-birt/src/main]

Here is a Springboot Starter project even.

[https://blog.innoventsolutions.com/innovent-solutions-blog/2020/04/getting-started-with-the-birt-spring-boot-starter.html]

Warning, the springboot starter project includes logging classes and will need to exclude other logging in your logging dependencies to get it to work.